# How to transfer an image from C++ to Unity3D using OpenCV?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine

I have a trouble in transferring an image from C++ to Unity3D(C#). I used OpenCV to read a `Mat` type image and get the data point with `img.data`. When I build the `dll` and call the corresponding function, I get error with all data in the bytes array is 0, so I want to know how to transfer an image from C++ to C#. Thank you.

Sorry for late reply, 
code shown as the follows:
`C++ code`:

```
DLL_API BYTE* _stdcall MatToByte()
{

    Mat srcImg = imread("F:\\3121\\image\\image_0\\000000.png");
    nHeight = srcImg.rows;
    nWidth = srcImg.cols;

    nBytes = nHeight * nWidth * nFlag / 8;
    if (pImg)
        delete[] pImg;

    pImg = new BYTE[nBytes];
    memcpy(pImg, srcImg.data, nBytes);
    return pImg;
}
```

`C# code`

```
    [DllImport("Display")]
    public static extern IntPtr MatToByte();

        byte[] Bytes = new byte[nBytes];
        IntPtr tmp =  MatToByte();
        Marshal.Copy(tmp, Bytes, 0, nBytes);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);
        texture.LoadImage(Bytes);
        left_plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
```

Comment: Need to see definition of the method you are using in c++ to get bytes.

Comment: Provide code examples of both C++ and C#, and give the error you got.

Comment: Well, first of all check if the image is correctly read by OpenCV (maybe there is a wrong path or whatever issue during the picture loading). Then, if the image is ok,  provide the code of the C# caller 'cause I guess could be there some type mismatching